# Unable to log output of "apachectl configtest" to a file

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, tee, piping

I want to log the output of the command "apachectl configtest" to a file. So I tried the following commands:

```
root@ubuntu:~# echo $(apachectl -t) >> /tmp/apache_config_check
[Sun Feb 21 14:35:23.614947 2016] [proxy_html:notice] [pid 29249] AH01425: I18n support in mod_proxy_html requires mod_xml2enc. Without it, non-ASCII characters in proxied pages are likely to display incorrectly.
Syntax OK
```

But It gave empty output:

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /tmp/apache_config_check 

root@ubuntu:~#
```

I also tried a variation on the command itself:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apachectl -t >> /tmp/apache_config_check
```

and a variation on tee:

```
root@ubuntu:~# $(apachectl -t) | tee /tmp/apache_config_check
```

Without luck.

I don't really know any other methods to pipe the output, nor I know why the above commands failed. Is it something fundamental?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `apachectl` is sending its output to STDERR instead of STDOUT.  So, you need to redirect STDERR as follows:

```
apachectl -t > /tmp/apache_config_check 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` is shell-script magic saying "redirect output on  file descriptor 2 (STDERR) to file descriptor 1 (STDOUT)".

Comment: Thank you for the solution + clear explanation! Is there a way to determine if a command uses STDERR or STDOUT? Or should this be mentioned in the man-page?

Comment: To actually determine where it sends it, one would have to test it.  For example `apachectl -t > STDOUT.output 2> STDERR.output` separates the output into the two different files.  In general, regular output should come to STDOUT and error messages to STDERR.  Often, it is mentioned in the manual page.  In this particular case it's complicated because the `apachectl` script just calls `/usr/sbin/httpd -t` and nowhere in the manual pages does it explain that that output goes to STDERR.